# Multiple cron jobs in different files in AWS ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I am using AWS ec2 for my projects.I Have more than 10 domain in one ec2 instance also which has more than 5 cron for each domain.Can i create different files for crontab. If create all the cron jobs code in a single file it is little bit confusing

Comment: Are you managing all of them with one user? If they are in different users then each user will have their own cron file.

Comment: currently only one user

Comment: Have a look at this: https://superuser.com/questions/391246/multiple-crontabs-for-one-user